# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Users'. It's throwing this error

Tags: json, angular, typescript

While I'm trying to read data from a json file and form a table using HTML, some part of the code is executing fine but some part of the code shows some index error. below I've shared all the necessary files. This is an Angular problem.
This is my json file

```
{
    "Users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Nitin",
        "lastName": "Rana",
        "email": "nitin.rana@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "2345678901",
        "salary": "25000"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Rajat",
        "lastName": "Singh",
        "email": "rajat.singh1@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "5637189302",
        "salary": "30000"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Rahul",
        "lastName": "Singh",
        "email": "rahul.singh1@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "5557189302",
        "salary": "40000"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "firstName": "Akhil",
        "lastName": "Verma",
        "email": "akhil.verma2@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "5690889302",
        "salary": "20000"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "firstName": "Mohan",
        "lastName": "Ram",
        "email": "mohan.ram1@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "7637189302",
        "salary": "60000"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "firstName": "Sohan",
        "lastName": "Rana",
        "email": "sohan.rana@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "3425167890",
        "salary": "25000"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "firstName": "Rajjev",
        "lastName": "Singh",
        "email": "rajeev.singh1@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "5637189302",
        "salary": "30000"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "firstName": "Mukul",
        "lastName": "Singh",
        "email": "mukul.singh1@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "5557189302",
        "salary": "40000"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "firstName": "Vivek",
        "lastName": "Verma",
        "email": "vivek.verma2@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "5690889302",
        "salary": "20000"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "firstName": "Shubham",
        "lastName": "Singh",
        "email": "shubham.singh@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "7637189502",
        "salary": "60000"
      }
    ]
  }
```

and this is my HTML file

```
<h1>Table using JSON Server API</h1>
<hr>


<table id="users">

  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
      {{col}}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td *ngFor="let col of index">
      {{user[col]}}

    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

In my output

```
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
      {{col}}
    </th>
```

this part of code is executing fine, but the below part is throwing some error saying that
 `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Users'.`

```
  <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td *ngFor="let col of index">
      {{user[col]}}

    </td>
```

Hope someone could help! This is just an index error which I couldn't figure out myself

Comment: User belongs to users, col belongs to index, the question is index belongs to what ? Where that index came from

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to populate your table using index, you might want to try index coming with *ngFor.

`*ngFor="let user of users; let i = index"`

`{{user[i]}}`